# How to append 2>nul into the bat script

Tags: for-loop

thanks for your time to advise me on this. This is my script in a bat file.

```
FOR /D %%p IN ("V:\StagingArea\stagingdownload\cs\or*") DO MOVE %%p "/Y  V:\StagingArea\stagingdownload\_download_archive\cs" 2>nul
```

Is the appended {2>nul} at the correct place? My script will end but 1 folder which appear in source and destination folder will not be copied over. My intention is to overwrite it even though it located at destination.

Comment: Hi Filip,thanks for your prompt response. The duplicate folder still don't copy over.

Comment: Had tried
FOR /D %%p IN ("V:\StagingArea\stagingdownload\cs\or*") DO MOVE %%p "V:\StagingArea\stagingdownload\_download_archive\cs /Y" 2>nul
but prompted 0 dir moved